# How to make AWS CLI avaliable in a docker ambient via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Kinda of a noob in Docker.

I run a Apache NiFi instance in a docker and I need to make AWS CLI avaliable to it.

How do I edit my docker-compose.yaml to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Docker image that has both Apache NiFi and the AWS CLI. You can use a simple Dockerfile like this one:

```
FROM apache/nifi

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    awscli \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

It will build an image that is based on Apache NiFi image and install `awscli` package in it.